# In Excel with AppleScript how can I get the column's numeric value without bringing in the entire column?

Tags: excel, applescript

In Excel with AppleScript I have a 10k row and about a 200 column XLSX. I can get the total number of used columns with:

```
set tCols to columns of used range of activeSheet
```

out of the 200ish columns all I need is around 10 so I've added them to a record like this:

```
set nRec to {"Mon","Tues","Wed"}
```

I can loop through the columns with:

```
repeat with i in tCols
    ## further code
end repeat
```

but when I try to evaluate what the present column's row 1 is it becomes performance heavy because it's evaluating everything in that column. When I dump the column's properties with the following tests:

```
return i ## gets base column properties
return cells of i ## target cell scope
return columns of i ## target's column scope
return value of rows of i
```

every command is evaluating the entire contents of that column. Is there a way in AppleScript and Excel to get just the column's alpha-numeric value (`A, B, C, D`) so I can write a condition to wether I should delete the entire column or not based on if it's included in my record?

My understanding from the docs is if I have the column value I can scope the range with something like `A1`. When I search on SO and MacScripter I'm only able to find solutions that bring in the entire column to evaluate.

Comment: If you change `set tCols to columns of used range of activeSheet` **to** `set tCols to a reference to columns of used range of activeSheet` is the performance any better?

Comment: No it's slower on the return of `tCols` and will not loop through as a reference when trying to return `name` of the properties dump: `repeat with i in tCols return name of i end repeat`

Answer (score 1):

This provides a list of columns whose row 2 contains a target value. For example data of 40 columns, I did a fill with 'Mon', 'Tue', etc… in row 2 of the first 21 columns (every day three times, and left the remaining 19 blank). The result is a list with the three matching column numbers per day. Hopefully I understood your objective.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet
        
        set uRange to used range
        set tRange to range "2:2" -- row 2
        
        -- Intersect to get second row of used range
        set iSect to intersect range1 range of uRange range2 range of tRange
        
        set valueList to value of cells of iSect as list --> list of every row 2 value
        
        -- index of cells which match desired value
        set matchList to {}
        set goalList to {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed"}
        repeat with a from 1 to count of valueList
            
            if item a of valueList is in goalList then
                copy a to end of matchList
            end if
        end repeat
        
    end tell
end tell
matchList --> {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16, 17}
```